# CoreLocation Updates with GPS

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, gps, core-location

Hi I'm developing on an iPad Mini 1st Gen with cellular and need to use its internal GPS to acquire lat/long coordinates. I'll be on a boat and will press a button that will save the coordinates into a text file on the iPad (Document's Directory). Then I'll sail 10 miles away and hit the button again which will append the new coordinates to the text file. I'll be doing this 8 times and should have 8 different pairs of coordinates. However, the app is very inconsistent and either keeps the same coordinates or doesn't acquire any at all. As a reminder I am not using wifi/cellular, only the internal GPS (the GPS on the boat is able to acquire signal so it is not a hardware problem). My code is below. Thanks in advance!

```
//in viewDidLoad

    self.locman = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locman.delegate = self;
    self.locman.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locman.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locman.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
```

//delegate method

```
#define REQ_ACC 10
#define REQ_TIME 10

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation* loc = locations.lastObject;
    CLLocationAccuracy acc = loc.horizontalAccuracy;
    NSDate* time = loc.timestamp;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = loc.coordinate;
    if (!self.startTime) {
        self.startTime = [NSDate date];
        return; // ignore first attempt
    }
    NSLog(@"%f", acc);
    NSTimeInterval elapsed = [time timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime];
    if (elapsed > REQ_TIME) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"This is taking too long");
        [self stopTrying];
        return;
    }
    if (acc < 0 || acc > REQ_ACC) {
        return; // wait for the next one
    }
    // got it
    NSLog(@"You are at: %f %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
    self.lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",coord.latitude];
    self.longString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",coord.longitude];
    [self stopTrying];
}


-(void) stopTrying {
    [self.locman stopUpdatingLocation];
    self.startTime = nil;
    self.trying = NO;
}
```

//This is in an IBAction (a button press when the user wants to record coordinates)

```
[self.locman startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: So do you keep the location updates running in the background? Do you start updates a few minutes before you want to record the state?

Comment: No, the updates start immediately upon the press of a UIButton and stop upon reaching the stopTrying method.

Comment: So you are allowing a maximum of 10 seconds to lock a location - not going to be enough...

Comment: Looks like it... Pham's suggestion of pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO seems to be giving me accurate results. However, this is just in the simulator with fake locations. I'll have to take the iPad outside and try it out.

Comment: I allowed 20 seconds instead of 10 and it worked perfectly on the simulator. However, it kept hanging on the real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set this `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO` with your `CLLocationManager`

It looks like `stopTrying` is never called (i guess, because of the newly init `time` and `elapsed`) so the GPS paused automatically.

Additionally, if you want a "timeout" timer for this method, you should start a `NSTimer` in you `IBAction` and call `stopTrying` and `invalidate` the timer inside it too.